# Flicker of Dividing Line Between Menu and Chosen Screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, hamburger-menu, react-navigation-drawer

I have a React Native project with Expo. There is a hamburger menu, and there is a strange flicker on the dividing line between the menu and the chosen screen.  Please see the attached video.

I'm using:

"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.0",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",

Any help to rectify this is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/assets/12520398/dc47cd2d-85b8-4848-8f37-9123944bd692

Comment: Does that happen on a physical device or an emulated one? I've seen such behavior on emulators (particularly with borders) where the border 'appears' to flicker.

Comment: Thank you. It happens on physical devices. I have not seen it in an emulator surprisingly.